# Pandas keep index order when vectorised calc between dataframes with duplicate indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have two `DataFrame`s (`df1` and `df2`) with matching indexes the resulting `Series` will be sorted when `df1["column"].subtract(df2["column"])`.

As long as `df1.index` doesn't contain duplicates, we can use `reindex`. But is there any way to keep the order of index in `df1` if the index contains duplicates? (We don't want to iterate over the rows so that is not an option)

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'identifier': list("ababc"), 
                    'column': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}).set_index('identifier')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'identifier': list("ac"),
                    'column': [2, 3]}).set_index('identifier')

df1['column'].subtract(df2["column"])

identifier
a   -1.0
a    1.0
b    NaN
b    NaN
c    2.0

df1['column'].subtract(df2["column"]).reindex(df1.index)
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Expected output:

```
identifier
a    -1.0
b    NaN
a    1.0
b    NaN
c    2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create helper `MultiIndex` by assign neste lists or add parameter `append=True` to [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then subtract by second level and last remove first helper level:

```
df1.index = [np.arange(len(df1)), df1.index]
s = df1['column'].subtract(df2["column"], level=1).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (s)
identifier
a   -1.0
b    NaN
a    1.0
b    NaN
c    2.0
Name: column, dtype: float64
```

Or:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'identifier': list("ababc"), 
                    'column': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}).set_index('identifier', append=True)

s = df1['column'].subtract(df2["column"], level=1).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Push into in online use `join` and `assign` new key

```
df1.assign(New=df1.reset_index().index).join(df2,lsuffix='x',rsuffix='y' ).\
       sort_values('New').\
         eval('column=columnx-columny')[['column']]
Out[142]: 
            column
identifier        
a             -1.0
b              NaN
a              1.0
b              NaN
c              2.0
```